# Why does clang++ lack forward list?

Tags: c++11, clang++

I wrote up a simple C++ program that relies on `forward_list` like

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::forward_list<int> my_list;
  my_list.push_front(3);
  std::cout << my_list.top() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile this program on my Mac with `clang++ my_program.cpp -std=c++11 -o my_program`, I get this error:

```
my_program.cpp:1:14: fatal error: 'forward_list' file not found
#include <forward_list>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Why can't clang find `forward_list`? Other C++11 features are working. For instance, the `auto` keyword works, albeit a warning appears that tells me that `auto` is a C++11 feature.

Comment: Not an answer, but `forward_list` doesn't have `top` member function.  Also I can't reproduce your error on Linux. Try to search `forward_list` header by hands in your clang's include folder.

Comment: Because Apple <censored>. Look at the -stdlib=libc++ option or install a recent gcc to get a recent standard library.

Comment: Clang is a *compiler*, and only that. It's the burden of the stdlib to provide all the standard headers.

Comment: @MarcGlisse `-stdlib=libc++` is the only way to go. Trying to find a particular version of libstdc++-v3 to play well with your particular version of Clang is a <censored> idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default clang++ uses an older gcc-4.2 std library which has no C++11 support.  You can tell clang to use a C++11-aware std::lib with the command `-stdlib=libc++`.  libc++ has `<forward_list>`.

Comment: When I add this flag, clang++ tells me it can't find iostream! `fatal error: 'iostream' file not found`

Comment: @NickDesaulniers: What platform are you on?

Comment: @NickDesaulniers: This sounds like an installation problem.  Try installing the latest version of Xcode.